# Multi lingual .properties files in Android API 33

Tags: android, mobile-development, resourcebundle, android-developer-api, android-api-33

Following attached screenshot shows my project folder structure,

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/yML4C.png)

And I am able to access those language properties files by following code,

```
locale = getCurrentLocale(curLocale);
resBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("res.raw.lang", locale);
```

But after I changed my app to API 33 and generated signed APK in release mode, I am not able to access these files and its throwing following error,

"java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name res/raw/lang, locale en_EN"

APK generated in debug mode is working, I am seeing this error only in apk generated in release mode.

Please help.

In Android API 31, its working fine.